# Check if relative URI exists

Tags: c#, .net, uri

I want to check if a URI returns a valid result.
Example:

```
String path = String.Format("{0}/agreements/{1}.gif", PicRoot, languageTwoLetterCode);
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));
...
```

This throws a notsuportedexception. So I figure I should be providing the absolute URI.
All examples I can find use a hardcoded root (like www.example.com). This is off course unacceptable because it is uncertain what the actual root of the website will be.

How can I either check the result from a relative URI or find the current root?
Are there better ways to check if say "/content/pics/agreements/en.gif" returns a gif or a 404?

Comment: Is this from within an ASP.Net website?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the root of the web site from the server object.

You could use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx) (see [also](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417074237/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/121799-1.shtml)) and then check if the physical path is on the server (use [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx))